# What is a prebuilt gcc?

Tags: gcc

I would like to know what they mean with "prebuilt gcc"?
gcc is the compiler, but what do they mean by prebuilt? And why does google offer a prebuilt gcc for their android. Can I just not use the regular gcc?

Comment: Who is "they"? What is the context? It could be as simple as "gcc binaries" (i.e. you don't need to build gcc yourself).

Comment: Well in this case I mean Google. I was looking at their source code and how to build their Google Glasses OS, and I saw that they recommend using a prebuilt GCC.
Why not use the Eclipse GCC?

Comment: It means a copy of GCC that you didn't build; it was built before you got hold of it.  The basic idea is to save you the time (a couple of hours) and disk space (several GiB while building) that are necessary for you to build it yourself.  See also [Reflections on Trusting Trust](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~rxin/db-papers/TrustingTrust-Thompson.pdf).

Comment: Eclipse GCC would be a pre-built GCC if you download it from one of the Eclipse web sites.

Comment: Does Eclipse GCC have support for ARM-processors? Or I have to Download a different GCC for Eclipse?

Comment: You'll have to look at what is provided (I don't know what GCC for Eclipse provides).  Are you running on an ARM machine?  Or are you going to be cross-compiling?  If you're going to cross-compile, it is a ***lot*** easier to get someone else's cross-compiler running than it is to create your own.  You need to know which platform you are developing on, and which platform you are targeting.  The cross-compiler will need to be suitable on both counts.

Answer (score 0):

GCC has a source code repository available via [SVN](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/download.html).

In some scenarios, you need to download the source code and [build](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html) the GCC yourself (specially when you have custom hardware). But for most cases, 'pre-built' GCC for your hardware and OS is enough.